# How do I change the order of $PATH?

Tags: bash, path

`echo $PATH`  gives me

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:/Users/pathreskoo/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

but when I want to change the order of `/usr/local/bin` to the front of `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin`, I type

```
sudo emacs /etc/paths
```

I only get

```
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
```

How can I insert `/usr/local/bin` in front of my `PATH`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can set your `PATH` in the file `.bash_profile`, which is in your home directory.

More specifically, you can simply add the following line to the end of that file

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

This results in `/usr/local/bin` being prepended to the existing `PATH`. In other words, the folder `/usr/local/bin` is inserted in front of your `PATH`, and so it would have the highest priority. You can also append a folder to your path by doing

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

In general, you can set the order of the folders or files that you export in a similar way as the following:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:/Users/pathreskoo/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

**Note**: *this is not the only place you can set the `PATH`, but it is a common one.*

Comment: It's safer to just add `/usr/local/bin` to the front of the path, rather than completely override the inherited value (`PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`). Duplicates don't cause any harm, and your path is unlikely to get so large as to cause performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your $PATH normally overridden by the initiation part of your shell. Normally follows the system-wide profile (/etc/profile), then user-side profile (if you use bash .profile, .bash_profile, .bashrc) and any source command in these files. The overridden command mainly in .bashrc

Edit you .bashrc file and find $PATH, you may find the export command and delete the path you do not want. export $PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH override the command user-wide.

Comment: would work better as a comment, as it doesn't stand by itself as an answer to the question... or perhaps it could use much editing! good luck.