# Eclipse/MinGW won't Link Libraries

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker, mingw

I am running Eclipse Oxygen trying to link GLFW to my project. I have 3 library files `glfw3.dll`, `libglfw3.a`, and `libglfw3dll.a`. I have tried with and without the lib prefix, the library path is included, and I have tried with and without the file extension.

Edit: The errors are `c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Users/leobr/Desktop/glfw-3.2.1.bin.WIN64/lib-mingw-w64/glfw3.dll`

`c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Users/leobr/Desktop/glfw-3.2.1.bin.WIN64/lib-mingw-w64/libglfw3.a`

`c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Users/leobr/Desktop/glfw-3.2.1.bin.WIN64/lib-mingw-w64/libglfw3dll.a`

Comment: Tried some solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683058/gcc-linking-libraries-not-found?rq=1 but I just got undefined reference errors to my OpenGL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My main problem was that I was using Win32MinGW and win64GLFW. I also had to link dll library instead of the normal one.